# Powershell script from task scheduler unable to work as intended

Tags: powershell

I have a script file that when ran from within ISE or from the powershell window it works fine. But when ran trough the task scheduler with "runas" the same account it only outputs half the data.

After some troubleshooting i have concluded that the part of the code that is not working is:

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase $OU -Filter {objectclass -eq "organizationalunit"} -SearchScope onelevel -Properties description | 
    % {
        $mailbox = @( get-user -OrganizationalUnit $_.distinguishedName -resultsize unlimited |
            ? { $_.title -ne "xxx" -and $_.RecipientType -eq "usermailbox" -and $_.RecipientTypeDetails -ne "RoomMailbox" } )
        if ($mailbox.count -gt 0) {
            $name = $_.name
            $mail_customer = $body
            $mail_customer += "<h3>"  + $name + "</h3>"
            $mail_customer += $mailbox | get-MailboxStatistics |
                select displayname, lastlogontime, @{ label = "Mailbox Size(MB)"; expression = {
                    if ($_.totalitemsize.value.toMB() -gt 25600) { "!!!" + $_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB() }
                    else { $_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB() }
                } } | Sort-Object displayname | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment | Out-String
            $count += $mailbox.count
            $stattable += @{$name = $mailbox.count}
            $mail_customer = $mail_customer | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '!!!', '<font color="#FF0000">' }
            if ( $_.description -ne $null ) {
                $mailaddresses = $_.description.split(",")
                Send-MailMessage `
                    -SmtpServer $SMTPserver `
                    -Encoding $encoding `
                    -From "$company <noreply@$companylower.se>" `
                    -To $mailaddresses `
                    -Subject "$company report - $name - $date" `
                    -BAH `
                    -Body $mail_customer
            }
        $mail += $mail_customer
        $mailaddresses = "";
        }
    }
```

I get the email but it does not include the information that these lines should output, any ideas?

Script is called like this: powershell -file c:\temp\scriptname.ps1

Comment: `Get-MailboxStatistics` requires membership of the `Organization Management` role-group in Exchange. Is the user account running the task member of the group?

Comment: the account is a member of Organization Management yes.

Comment: Can you please try to output `$mail_customer` just before the mail is sent, to check if it holds what you need ?

Comment: when ran from ISE/console it contains the information i need, when ran ask task, it outputs nothing. I'm running as the same user as the task... Is there a different property when running as a task? i think not as i have never had this issue ever before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic case of not running something elevated. Nothing in the code was wrong.

In Task Scheduler, make sure "Run with highest privileges" is ticked in for the task or it will not work.